# Blazor Project Data Feching issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have converted my old blazor project to .net8 web App and I have set client index page as a homePage. When It starts all stores are shown that are fetched with the help of Api.

No action is performed when click on any buttons. Like by clicking eye button that shows store Products.
I have created a Modal Component with the help of javascript and bootsraps.
When The project starts, By clicking **info** and **Contact** button only title is shown but their data is not shown why?
[Not Data Fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZc8U.png)

After some time project Automatically loads and then all the project works fine.

Can anyone help me. what we have to do as my project fetched data before loading and why my project loads after some times automatically?

You can see the behavior of my project by visiting our webpage
[Online Market Place](https://market.powerlatics.com)

Comment: I think you have to set the Rendermode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: It might due to the [render mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which is new in blazor web app in .net 8. If your old project is web assmebly, you might keep using web assmebly. If the old project  is blazor server, then you might convert to blazor web app.

Comment: by the way, here's a [migration guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) which might help you as well.